# Cakephp 3: Getting foreach array from associative table in view.ctp

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0

I'm in a view looking at a table for Annual Operating Budget. I have many budget expenses associated with a single Annual Operating Budget. I would like to list those Expenses in the view. How do I do a foreach statement for those?

in my AnnualOperatingBudgetController:

```
public function view($id = null)
    {
        $annualOperatingBudget = $this->AnnualOperatingBudgets->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Azinstitutions', 'BudgetExpenses']
        ]);

        $this->set('annualOperatingBudget', $annualOperatingBudget );
    }
```

When I look at the Variables in debugkit i can see them.

```
annualOperatingBudget (array)
id 2
azinstitutions_id 2
budget_year 2015
assumptions
budget_expenses (array)
0 (App\Model\Entity\BudgetExpense)
1 (App\Model\Entity\BudgetExpense)
2 (App\Model\Entity\BudgetExpense)
3 (App\Model\Entity\BudgetExpense)
4 (App\Model\Entity\BudgetExpense)
5 (App\Model\Entity\BudgetExpense)
azinstitution (array)
[new] (false)
[accessible] (array)
[dirty] (empty)
[original] (empty)
[virtual] (empty)
[errors] (empty)
[invalid] (empty)
[repository] AnnualOperatingBudgets
```

but I can't use

```
<?php foreach ($annualOperatingBudget as ?): ?>
```

there is only one. How do I reach the associated array for the foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$annualOperatingBudget` is an array you can access the expenses with:

```
<?php foreach ($annualOperatingBudget['budget_expenses'] as $expense): ?>
```

If it is an object then access them with:

```
<?php foreach ($annualOperatingBudget->budget_expenses as $expense): ?>
```

Comment: I believe it is an object. It is one AnnualOperatingBudget with an attached array of expenses. I'll try the second one out when I get back to the office.

Comment: Your second option worked perfect. I was able to get the array needed. Thank you Bill